# $http timeout test jasmine angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test my module `APICompare`

```
var APIClient = function($http) {
    this.send = function(data) {
        $http({
            method: data.method,
            url: data.url,
            headers: data.headers,
            data: data.data
        }).success(function(response, status){
            data.success(response, status);
        }).error(function(response, status){
            data.error(response, status);
        });
    }
}

angular.module('api.client', []).factory('APIClient', ['$http' function($http)
{
    var client = new APIClient($http);

    return {
        send: function(data)
        {
            return client.send(data);
        },
    }

}]);
```

And the test

```
describe('send', function() {

    var apiClient, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('compare'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        apiClient = $injector.get('APIClient');
    }));

    it ('Should check if send() exists', function() {
        expect(apiClient.send).toBeDefined();
    });

    it ('Should send GET request', function(done) {
        var url = '/';

        $httpBackend.when('GET', url).respond({});

        apiClient.send({
            method: 'GET'
            url: url,
            data: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            success: function(data, status) {
                console.log(status);
                done();
            },
            error: function(data, status) {
                console.log(status);
                done();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But each time I have

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) send Should send GET request FAILED
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Ti seems the `$httpBackend.when('GET', url).respond({});` is ignored but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`$httpBackend.flush`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#flushing-http-requests).

You should do this when the `http` request has been made -- most likely right before your assertions. This also synchronizes the request and eliminates the need for the `success` and `error` callbacks.

Also note that if there is an error, you probably want to call `done` with the error so that your test fails -- unless you *want*.